# Robots and RTOS

Tags: mobile-robot, real-time

Many computing platforms used by robots are not real time(ex Jetson).

How are real time constraints handled in real robots? Are all software transfered into a hardware solution with real time performance? How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, for example many robot computers are based on the linux real-time kernels to handle the real-time constraints.

For small robots for teaching like the [turtlebot](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/overview/) uses a raspberry pi for the high-level control, and a motor control board for the real-time control.

Another example is the [Ball balancing robot](https://github.com/mindThomas/Kugle-Embedded) that uses an STM32 Nucleo board with the free RTOS kernel to handle the real-time control and communicates to the onboard computer for autonomous navigation.